# ASP.NET API issue: The instance of entity type 'Pizza' cannot be tracked, another instance with same key value is already being tracked

Tags: api, asp.net-core

If i want to post this CollectionModel with more Pizza than one, it comes to a issue.
The CollectionModel:

```
public class DeliveryCollectionModel
{
    public Delivery? Delivery { get; set; }
    public List<Pizza>? Pizza { get; set; }
}
```

Here ist the issue:

```
The instance of entity type 'Pizza' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Here is the post:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("add/w/Pizza")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DeliveryCollectionModel>> AddDeliveryWithPizza(DeliveryCollectionModel model)
    {
        _dataContext.Delivery.Add(model.Delivery);
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        string id = model.Delivery.Id.ToString(); // It have a ID with int and A_I

        

        foreach (var currentPizza in model.Pizza) // Here is the ID in string and non A_I
        {
            currentPizza.Id = "G" + id;
            _dataContext.Pizza.Add(currentPizza);
        }
        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok("G" + id);
    }
```

Whats the matter?

Comment: To be honest, I think the issue is relate to the `Add` method though I didn't test in my side, you may refer to [this document](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/add-record-add-multiple-records-in-entity-framework/) and check the `AddRange` method. Pls kindly let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

before saving DataContext changes add this

```
Entry<DeliveryCollectionModel>(model).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. But if i do this, this issue comes: "The entity type 'DeliveryCollectionModel' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model."